# Modifying Form Value As User Types

Tags: angular

I'm trying to modify an input value as a user types. Consider this simplified example:

app.component.html

```
<label for="testInput">Enter Text Here: </label>
<input
  id="testInput"
  type="text"
  [ngModel]="inputVal"
  (ngModelChange)="handleChange($event)"
>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  inputVal: string = '';
  handleChange(newVal) {
    let justDigits = newVal.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    console.log('The new value with just digits: ', justDigits);
    this.inputVal = justDigits;
  }
}
```

The console log clearly shows that `handleChange` is running and strips out non-digits. However, the form value doesn't reflect that. For instance if you were to type '123abc', the form value would display just that. The console log would show '1', then '12', then '123' four times.

Coming from a lot of React, this is bizarre. What's going on here?

Comment: you need to understand how ``ngModelChange`` works . Everytime the input changes , ``ngModelChange`` is called . If you type 1 , ``ngModelChange`` is called . and then again ``ngModelChange`` is called when you type 2 next . Everytime , your input is changing and hence the ``console.log `` prints 1 ,12, 123,123 , 123 , 123 (last 3 times 123 is due to ``replace() `` ) . This is how angular works and how ngModelChange works .

Comment: I suggest you to use `(keyup)` event instead of `(ngModelChange)`

Comment: @CruelEngine The surprising was not the console log. That worked as I expected. The surprising thing was that setting inputVal did not change the input displayed to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is change detection, if you type in '1a2b3c' you will see the following on the page itself:

1
1a
12
12b
123
123c

This is because `inputVal` doesn't change if your input ends with letters.

A possible solution is to trigger change detection. This can be done as follows:

```js
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  inputVal: string = '';

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  handleChange(newVal) {
    let justDigits = newVal.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    console.log('The new value with just digits: ', justDigits);
    this.inputVal = null;        // Change the model and trigger a change detection
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    this.inputVal = justDigits;// Change it again, and let the change detection happen
  }
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l14ehr

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of scenario, the best would be to have `pipe`. In your case you can have `pipe` which will filter everything except number.

Here the NumberDirective which allow numbers only.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[numbersOnly]'
})
export class NumberDirective {

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange(event) {
    const initalValue = this._el.nativeElement.value;
    this._el.nativeElement.value = initalValue.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, '');
    if (initalValue !== this._el.nativeElement.value) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }

}
```

Here is the working demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-numbers-only-directive-2qm1cc

Comment: Sure. But I'm more interested in figuring out why this isn't working...

Comment: This also doesn't work, the value doesn't reach the model: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-numbers-only-directive-c3efi1